# Why is my select statement returning old data after a working update statement?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I run the code below on my express server. My goal is to update the database then, query the updated table. Everything is working except the query does not return updated results. If I run it a second time it returns the correct results for the first update.

```
        //// Run Update
        var db = new sqlite3.Database(myFile);
        var UpdateStatement = "UPDATE Employees SET Firstname = '"+Firstname+"', Lastname = '"+Lastname+"' WHERE id = "+ID+";";
        db.run(UpdateStatement);    
        db.close();

        //// Query table    
        var SELECTSTATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM Employees ;";  
        db = new sqlite3.Database(scheduleFile);        
        db.all(SELECTSTATEMENT,[],(err, rows) => {  if (err) { console.log("error at get /db.all Select  "); throw err; }   
            var strArr = JSON.stringify(rows);
            response.send(strArr);// Does not send back updated results.            
            db.close();
        });
```

Im guessing the database variable is still stale even after I create a new variable?

Comment: use select inside a callback of update statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//create sql statement and bind the parameters
var db = new sqlite3.Database(myFile);
var UpdateStatement = "UPDATE Employees SET Firstname = ?, Lastname = ? WHERE id = ?;";


// run statement and get the callback once its done
db.run(UpdateStatement,[firstName, lastName, id], function(err){
     // if err occured return the error
      if(err)
        return err
     // else return the response
      var SELECTSTATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM Employees ;";  
            db = new sqlite3.Database(scheduleFile);        
            db.all(SELECTSTATEMENT,[],(err, rows) => {  if (err) { console.log("error at get /db.all Select  "); throw err; }   
                var strArr = JSON.stringify(rows);
                response.send(strArr);// Does not send back updated results.            
                db.close();
            });

    });
```

Comment: Yup thank you. Putting the select statement inside a callback worked.